# mod_rewrite messing with sessions

Tags: session, mod-rewrite, submit, form-submit, csrf

I've been having a problem with mod_rewrite and sessions. I've a csrf token that is stored in a session everytime you visit the page but the problem is that when you submit a form the mod_rewrite before submitting the post it loads the page twice. So the csrf token changes before the post data arrives and it does not validate the submit.

I've been looking everywhere, I've changed the htaccess multiple times but it doesnt changes anything, it keeps happening.

**If I dissable the url rewrite it works perfectly.**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^actualidad/(.*)    /actualidad-info.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^campana/(.*)   /campanas-info.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^evento/(.*)    /evento-info.php?slug=$1 [QSA,L]
```